# Sync Gta 5 online character to Xbox live

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Is it possible to transfer my GTA V online character from my PlayStation 3 to my Xbox 360? I don't want to start all over.

Answer (score 1):

According to the information from Rockstar Support found [here](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-PC), You can transfer your progress to next generation consoles(Xbox one, PS4) and to a PC with the help of your Rockstar social club account. They have not mentioned about character transfer from PS3 to Xbox 360 in the provided link.

You can give it a try if you want with the procedure mentioned in their support link which I have given but, you will have only one chance and there are lot of limitations. Proceed at your own risk.

You can also post a question in Rockstar support for a definitive answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Its currently not possible to transfer data from PS3 to Xbox 360. GTA characters now can not be transferred to next-gen anymore. So i guess your data is stuck on the Xbox. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

The character transfer option has been removed, so you **Cannot** transfer anymore, Rockstar support might be able to help you if they're feeling generous though. But seeing how old this post is, I don't know if this still matters. If you already did it, please close the question in the future.